# Infinite, totally ordered and well ordered sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, well-orders, alternative-set-theories

It's quite easy to show that a finite set is well ordered iff it is totally ordered.
Is the converse also true? That is: is it true that a set is infinite iff it admits a total order which is not a well order? (For the sake of brevity, I shall write t.o. and w.o. for total order and well order, respectively)

The if part follows from the previous observation (t.o.+finiteness implies w.o.), so the question becomes

> Is it true that a set is infinite only if it admits a total order which is not a well order?

I know that every set admits a w.o.  (and thus a t.o.); still, answering the question requires to prove (or to disprove) that t.o.≠w.o., and this is out of my reach.

The question supposes ZFC but every other set theory is accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to prove that $A$ is finite if and only if there is an order $<$ on $A$, such that $(A,<)$ and the reverse order $(A,>)$ are both well-orders.

Now, note that the reverse order of a total order is again a total order, and so if $A$ is infinite, there is a well-ordering on $A$, $<$, such that $(A,>)$ is not a well-order itself. (Of course, one can show that this is true for *any* well-ordering of an infinite set.)

---

Just a remark on the Axiom of Choice, the above holds for $\sf ZF$ as well, although it is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that there are sets which do not admit *any* total orders, let alone well-orders.

But a curious thing is that if we change "there exists an order ..." to "every well-order $<$ satisfies ...", then any set which cannot be well-ordered satisfies the definition vacuously. And therefore the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the statement "a set $A$ is finite if and only if for every well-order on $A$, the reverse order is also a well-order".

Comment: Please participate [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52383196#52383196)

Answer (score 6):

Not my area of expertise but I will suggest an answer.

If a $S$ is infinite, well order it. An initial segment will be the natural numbers with their usual order. Then reorder that initial segment using a bijection to the rational numbers to transfer the not-well-ordered numerical order on the rationals.

If this is wrong someone will point that out. Then I can delete it, or leave it as an instructive false start.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: How can we be sure that rearranging the order gives as an order?

Comment: @GabrieleCassese You create a new ordering on the target space effectively ordered by the base space. The ordering may not be the same as the typical ordering on $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: You can even exchange the initial segment $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm sorry, but I do not understand: how can we be sure that in this new order $\Bbb Q$ is not well ordered? After all, we know there is a order in which it is (thanks to AC)

Comment: @GabrieleCassese It's actually the other way around: we are ordering the natural numbers according to the rationals, thanks to the bijection between these two sets.

Comment: @GabrieleCassese It's not a _well_ ordering, but it is an ordering (actually a total ordering)! There's a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ so you can translate an ordering from one to the other. When you do this to go from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Q$, the ordering will not the same as the ordering $\Bbb Q$ inherits from $\Bbb R$, however. (The elements will be permuted all over the place. Consult your favorite bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Q$ to see how the elements will be reordered.)